# Error in GLMM models to assess Crossed and nested Count data in R

Tags: r, random, count, nested, lme4

=======

I need to understand what factors can explain the implementation of a directive.  My design includes Biogeographic Region with 2 Levels, a nested variable within Biogeographic Region - Marine Sub-Unit - with 3 levels within each Biogeographic Region level and Criteria (16 levels) and Groups (11 levels). Each Marine Sub-unit includes counts concerning Criteria and Group. All my factors are categorical.

---

An example of a data frame, sum, is:

Biog_Reg    Marine.Sub.Unit Criteria Group                Count

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Benthic habitats         1

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Fish                    15

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Marine mammals           6

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Marine turtles           6

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Pelagic habitats         0

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Plankton                 0

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Rock & Biogenic Reef     0

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Seabirds                14

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.1      Sedimentary habitat      1

Celtic Seas FR_Celtic Seas  1.2      Fish                     0

---

Since I am addressing nested count data and I want to access all proper interactions, I am trying to use GLMM to perform the analysis. I have tested several models but the most complete includes the following design:

Model3 <- glmer (Count ~ Biog_Reg + Criteria + Group + Biog_Reg: Criteria+ Biog_Reg:Group + (1|Marine.Sub.Unit/Biog_Reg), family = poisson (), data = sum)

(I understand that going instead for the following model would be easier but it simply wouldn't run: 
Model3 <- glmer (Count ~ Biog_Reg * Criteria * Group + (1|Marine.Sub.Unit/Biog_Reg), family = poisson (), data = sum) )

However, the model takes a very long time to resolve and when it does, provides the following errors:

*"**Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 54 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
     vcov(x)     if you need it
convergence code: 0
unable to evaluate scaled gradient
Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 2 negative eigenvalues
failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
Warning messages:
1: In vcov.merMod(object, use.hessian = use.hessian) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX"***

I am relatively new in GLM in general, so I have several questions:

1. Do I have the type of model and model syntaxe correct? My variable is naturally nested, i.e. each Marine Sub-unit only belong to one of the two Biogeogrpahic Region, so should a simpler anova solve this?
2. In spite of the errors, the model provides results for each level of
   each factor individually. If the model is correct, how can I obtain
   the results for the factor?
3. Should I nest Criteria and Group within Marine Sub-Unit, evend though they are not ramdom? If so, how is the sintaxe for it?
4. Should I consider Hurdle models instead?

I have already read a huge amount of information but considering: *"Schielzeth, H. and Nakagawa, S. (2013), Nested by design: model fitting and interpretation in a mixed model era."*
I should go for mixed models and GLMM with Poisson distribution. This should handle count data. I have encountered many resembling questions but none specifically answered my doubts.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked a lot of questions that simply require more reading on your side. For example, it looks like you include your nested variables as a nested random effects rather than a fixed effects (intercept varying among Marine.Sub.Unit and among Biog_Reg within Marine.Sub.Unit). It is critical to understand the difference between fixed and random effects before choosing to use a mixed model. If you do want to include random effects, I recommend starting with Ben Bolker's [GLMM FAQ document](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) and his amazing [Worked Examples](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html).

You will also probably need to do likelyhood ratio tests to determine if the fixed variables you're interested in have any effect on the count data.

Hope that helps get you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. You are totally correct when you say that I have to clarify if my variable is random or fixed. That has been my doubt from the beginning; this is sometimes difficult to define. In my case, Biogeographic Region includes 3 Marine Units that represent about 80% of the entire universe of each Biogeographic Region and in fact I am interested in those specific units, so I could  consider them as fixed. But, on the other hand, and considering the definition of random and fixed variables I thought I had to treat them as random. Can I ask your opinion on this?